# Javascript - simple OOP encapsulation

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

```
let client = {
    main_account_balance: 0,
    balance_setter: function(value) {
      console.log(value);
      console.log('balance_setter');
      this.main_account_balance = value;
    }
};
```

whenever client's field main_account_balance is being set like this:

```
client.main_account_balance = 15;
```

It works perfectly fine. The problem arises whenever I am trying to use:

```
client.balance_setter(15);
```

It does not change value of

```
main_account_balance
```

at all

Comment: This works fine for me. `client.balance_setter(15); console.log(client)` shows the object with a balance of 15.

Comment: Ummmm I don't think so!

Comment: Where you are calling client.balance_setter(), first console.log(client) to see if the object's in scope

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick if the object wasn't in scope wouldn't trying to call `balance_setter()` result in an error?

Comment: The OP has accepted the most useless answer in the entire Stackoverflow's universe!

Comment: I am getting quite confused. Whenever I was calling client.balance_setter(15); it used to result in not setting anything. 
Right now, it works perfectly fine.
I literally have no idea of why it behaves in such a manner - is anyone able to explain it a little bit to me?
Or let's do this in another way - is there a better way to define OOP based objects in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me.

```js
let client = {
    main_account_balance: 0,
    balance_setter: function(value) {
      this.main_account_balance = value;
      //console.log('balance_setter');
      //console.log(this.main_account_balance);
    }
};

function increment() {
 client.balance_setter(client.main_account_balance+1);
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = 'main_account_balance = '+client.main_account_balance
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', increment);
```

```html
<button id="button">
click
</button>
<h1 id="value">

</h1>
```